# LED light bulbs, RFI, and garage door opener

Tags: garage-door-opener

I had to install new garage door opener (old one fried the lamp relay when the bulb burned out and arced), and noticed in the instructions not to use LED light bulbs because of possible RFI.  After some Google searches I was able to verify that, indeed, LED bulbs can create so much interference as to render the opener inoperable. There were also several articles I found that suggested using bulbs with the FCC logo imprinted on the side of the lamp base, which are generally about twice the price of the non-FCC compliant bulbs.
Has anyone found an LED light bulb that will work with a garage door opener?
Edit: new opener is Chamberlain LW5000EV

Comment: You shouldn't be using non-part-15 compliant LED lamps in the first place...sheesh!

Comment: Well, that was certainly helpful.

Comment: So...would such a light bulb, which I assume would have the FCC logo on it, not interfere with one's garage door opener.

Comment: It won't be as likely to interfere @BillOer, or at least that's what the idea is.

Comment: A bulb that doesn't comply with FCC regs could interfere with far more than just your garage door opener. I doubt they're legal to sell in the first place.

Comment: Because RFI is not a natural side effect of LEDs. RFI is caused by cheap and lazy misdesign of the electronic driver module which conditions AC power for use by the inherently DC LED. The FCC prohibits these bad designs from our shores, but between epacket delivery straight from Shenzhen, and the big box stores essentially smuggling cheapies in, the market is flooded with cheap junk.  This sets a psychological thing called your **price expectation**, and you now consider quality to be unreasonable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chamberlain has a [PDF guide listing LED bulb compatibility](http://www.liftmaster.com/Catalogresourcesv3/en-us/shared/files/tucmanuals/LED%20Bulb%20Compatibility_011714.pdf), which includes your unit.  More specifically, it lists:

```
|-----------|---------------------------------|--------------|
|           |                                 | Incandescent |
| Make      | Model                           | equivalent   |
|-----------|---------------------------------|--------------|
| Phillips  | 425256                          |      40w     |
| ECO SMART | ECS A19CW 60W E120              |      60W     |
| ECO SMART | ECS GP19 W27 40WE FR 120 DG 2PK |      40W     |
| CREE      | BA19-04527OMF-12DE26-2U100      |      40W     |
| 3M        | RRA19B4                         |      60W     |
| Sylvania  | 72554                           |      60W     |
| FEIT      | BPAG800DM-LED                   |      60W     |
| FEIT      | R20_DM_LED                      |      45W     |
|-----------|---------------------------------|--------------|
```

That guide is from January 2014, so more bulbs may be compatible, but it doesn't look like they've issued anything more recent.

Comment: I bought a pair of Sylvania/Osram Ultra LED 17-watt 100-watt equivalent bulbs, and they work perfectly.  No interference and I don't have to worry about the bulb arcing and frying the logic board when it burns out. He11, the bulb will probably last longer than the opener.

Answer (score 3):

My Craftsman garage opener (model 139.53985DM) installed new in Nov. of 2010 suddenly started being very difficult to close.  All other functions normal.  I finally realized that it was after I had replaced the regular lights with LEDs.  I used Sylvania OSRAM 60 watt equivalent bulbs.  When I swapped out LEDs with incandescent bulbs, the door closed normally.  I also replaced normal bulbs with LEDs on my newer Craftsman opener (model 139.54985).  The newer opener was not affected by the LEDs. I have since discovered that the LED power supply in the base of the bulb switches off and on rapidly to save on energy consumption.  It is this switching that causes the Radio Frequency Interference (RFI), not the LED itself. Sylvania OSRAM LED lighting has built in circuitry to reduce RFI and is compliant with an established FCC requirement, however older equipment which broadcasts a radio signal may not have considered RFI.  I think it is wise to buy LED bulbs with printed FCC compliance (like Sylvania OSRAM) but in addition, placing one LED bulb near any older broadcast device to check for interference is wise before you buy more LEDs.  Steve18039 May 2, 2016

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. Very cool sleuthing, and great information: thanks.

Comment: An AM radio will suffice.  I consider this an object lesson in not buying bulbs off the bottom shelf.  Power factor correction technology is not that hard to add to an LED, but some executives would rather put that cost in their own pockets.

Comment: Yeah, the beancounters are Madman Muntz in disguse these days, and the EMI suppression components are often the first things to go on bottom-shelf bulbs.

Answer (score 2):

The Genie Company has a guide for LED lamps that are compatible with their rolling-code Intellicode radio links, found at http://www.geniecompany.com/data/news/press-release_led-replacement-bulb-notice_09-24-2014.pdf, dated 14 September 2014.

```
|-----------|---------------------------------|--------------|
|           |                                 | Incandescent |
| Make      | Model                           | equivalent   |
|-----------|---------------------------------|--------------|
| Phillips  | SlimStyle 9290002707            |      60w     |
| GE        | Energy Smart LED11DA19V2/827S   |      60w     |
| GE        | Energy Smart LED7DA19V2/827S    |      40w     |
| Utilitech | Pro LED LA19DM/CL/LED           |      40W     |
| Utilitech | Pro LED YGA03A08-7W-850         |      40W     |
| Utilitech | Pro LED LA19DM/LEDG2            |      40W     |
|-----------|---------------------------------|--------------|
```

I've also had success with GE "bright stik" LED lamps in an old (ca. 1990) Stanley garage door opener, which is fitted with two lamp sockets.  The bright stik lamps are not dimmable, and they have an attractive price of around US$3 each in a package of three.  They do produce a bit of noise in the AM radio band, but have so far caused no problems in the garage door opener, either with operating range or reliability, especially while closing the door with the lamps on.  GE bright stik lamps appeared on the market late in 2014, after the Chamberlain and Genie guides were published.

Answer (score 2):

The Genie Company has came out with a new LED light bulb designed specifically for garage door openers.  The LED bulb reduces or eliminates radio frequency interference with the garage door openers remote. The bulb works on any brand garage door opener that has a standard light cavity. Here is more information on the Genie LED light bulb: http://www.geniecompany.com/garage-door-openers/accessories/led-light-bulb.aspx